# How to keep multiple editor tool enabled at once in Unity GUI?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, unity-editor

I have created a simple custom editor tool, which allows me to keep mouse position in a straight line. I require this to draw texture on a terrain in a straight line. Unfortunately, when I enable "Paint texture" tool in the terrain editor in inspector, my custom tool gets disabled and vice-versa. How can I keep both my custom tool and terrain paint tool enabled at once?

Custom tool selected but paint texture is deactivated-
[image: Custom tool selected but paint texture is deactivated]

Custom tool got deselected on paint texture selection-
[image: Custom tool got deselected on paint texture selection]

Following is the OnToolGUI method

```
    public override void OnToolGUI(EditorWindow window)
    {
        HandleUtility.AddDefaultControl(GUIUtility.GetControlID(FocusType.Passive));
        Event e = Event.current;
        if (!(window is SceneView))
            return;

        if (!ToolManager.IsActiveTool(this))
            return;

        if (e.shift)
        {
            if (e.type == EventType.MouseDown)
            {
                if (e.button == 0)
                {
                    downY = e.mousePosition.y;
                }
            }
            if (e.type == EventType.MouseDrag)
            {
                if (e.button == 0)
                {
                    e.mousePosition = new Vector2(e.mousePosition.x, downY);
                    Debug.Log("Mouse Position: " + e.mousePosition);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think the tools are simply exclusive .. probably not much you can do about this - except putting the option to enable/disable this somewhere else

Comment: @derHugo I think this might be the issue, as no other tools can be selected at once either. So now, Instead of making a tool, I moved the above code in OnSceneGUI(), which is activated when a gameobject is selected and its working as expected.

Comment: I think you could make this a general tool usable via the header menu - just enable/disable a flag in [`EditorPrefs`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorPrefs.html) (pretty much like `PlayerPrefs` but for the editor itself) .. and accordingly attach a listener to [`SceneView.duringSceneGui`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneView-duringSceneGui.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments I guess it simply is the nature of the tools that they are exclusive and you can only have one active at a time.

As alternative I would rather simply

- enable/disable this via a general header menu entry
- (optionally) store that decision persistent in [`EditorPrefs`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorPrefs.html) (pretty much like `PlayerPrefs` but for the editor itself)
- and accordingly attach a listener to [`SceneView.duringSceneGui`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneView-duringSceneGui.html)

This could look somewhat like e.g.

```
public static class StraightLineTool
{
    // Used for the displayed menu labels 
    // and also simply (ab)used as the unique key for the EditorPrefs
    private const string k_MenuName = "My Tools/Straight Line Tool";

    private static float downY;

    // Property for simplifying access and setting more centralized
    private static bool IsEnabled
    {
        get => EditorPrefs.GetBool(k_MenuName, false);
        set => EditorPrefs.SetBool(k_MenuName, value);
    }

    // method to be called when clicking the menu button
    [MenuItem(k_MenuName)]
    private static void ToggleEnabled()
    {
        IsEnabled = !IsEnabled;

        ApplySettings();
    }

    // adding a checkmark when is enabled and simply always allow to click it
    [MenuItem(k_MenuName, true)]
    private static bool ToggleEnabledValidate()
    {
        Menu.SetChecked(k_MenuName, IsEnabled);
        return true;
    }

    // Called on every project loading or code recompilation
    [InitializeOnLoadMethod]
    private static void Initialize()
    {
        EditorApplication.delayCall -= ApplySettings;
        EditorApplication.delayCall += ApplySettings;
    }

    private static void ApplySettings()
    {
        // remove so only happening once
        EditorApplication.delayCall -= ApplySettings;

        SceneView.duringSceneGui -= OnSceneGUI;

        if (IsEnabled)
        {
            // if enabled start listening
            SceneView.duringSceneGui += OnSceneGUI;
        }
    }

    // Callback listening to any SceneView.duringSceneGui
    private static void OnSceneGUI(SceneView sceneView)
    {
        // Not sure tbh what this does or if you need it still in this approach
        // HandleUtility.AddDefaultControl(GUIUtility.GetControlID(FocusType.Passive));
        var currentEvent = Event.current;

        if (currentEvent.shift)
        {
            if (currentEvent.type == EventType.MouseDown)
            {
                if (currentEvent.button == 0)
                {
                    downY = currentEvent.mousePosition.y;
                }
            }

            if (currentEvent.type == EventType.MouseDrag)
            {
                if (currentEvent.button == 0)
                {
                    currentEvent.mousePosition = new Vector2(currentEvent.mousePosition.x, downY);
                    Debug.Log("Mouse Position: " + currentEvent.mousePosition);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

=> using this the tool will be enabled/disabled persistent even when restarting Unity

[image]

---

Then using this as start point you can probably still try to somehow integrate this somewhere more nicely into the SceneView menus - but maybe that is also overkill ;)

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely try this.

Comment: Additionally, as per my understanding, that HandleUtility line basically overrides some default Unity controls. I added that line, as i was having an issue where mouse drag and mouse up were not being detected. But that was in OnToolsGUI() method. This is not required in OnSceneGUI(), and rather causes more issues, such as not being able to select objects in the scene view. Thanks again.